# Show that $\prod x_i \ge 1$ is a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm trying to generalize [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2931101/342736) question to arbitrary $n$ dimensions, i.e. to show that $C = \{x\in \mathbb R^n_{++} : \prod_i^nx_i \ge 1  \}$ is convex.

At first I thought maybe through induction, but I reached a dead end there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set can be expressed as
$$\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i \geq 0 \right\},$$
which is convex as $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i$ is a concave function.

Comment: can you elaborate why a set is convex if it's an inequality involving a function of concave?

Comment: This is the good answer.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli suppose $x$ and $y$ are in $C$, then $g(x)\geq 0$ and $g(y)\geq 0$, so $g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda) g(y) \geq 0$ by concavity of $g$, so the midpoint is also in $C$ (for any $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$).

Comment: yeah also by the fact that -concave = convex. And a level set of convex function (i.e. convex < c) is convex.

Answer (score 1):

By [weighted AM GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality),
for any $(x_i), (y_i) \in C$ and $t \in (0,1)$, we have

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (tx_i + (1-t)y_i) \ge
\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^t y_i^{1-t} = \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^t \left(\prod_{i=1}^n y_i\right)^{1-t} \ge 1^t 1^{1-t} = 1$$