# Prove $f(x, y) = \frac{x^2}{y}$ is a convex function on the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0\}$

Tags: convex-analysis

> Prove $f(x, y) = \frac{x^2}{y}$ is a convex function on the set $\{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0\}$.

---

**Attempt**

I start with the basic convexity, i.e.,

\begin{align}
f( \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2) \leq \alpha_1 f(x_1) + \alpha_2f(x_2) \ ,
\end{align}

where $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 1$. Let $z = (x,y)$, then

\begin{align}
f( \alpha z_1 + (1-\alpha) z_2) \leq \alpha f(z_1) + (1-\alpha)f(z_2) \ ,
\end{align}

How to proceed from here? Can this be proved by perspective function? If so, how to prove that?

Comment: Inasmuch as copying the first line to the second line, it is the "right path", yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A twice continuously differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set.
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{y}$$
Partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{2x}{y}, \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = -\frac{x^2}{y^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{2}{y}, \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} = -\frac{2x}{y^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x} = -\frac{2x}{y^2}, \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = \frac{2x^2}{y^3}$$

Hessian matrix:
$$H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{y} & -\frac{2x}{y^2} \\
    -\frac{2x}{y^2} & \frac{2x^2}{y^3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Sylvester's criterion is used to prove that matrix is positive semidefinite:
matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all leading minors are non-negative.

$$\Delta_{(1)} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{2}{y} >= 0$$
$$\Delta_{(2)} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = \frac{2x^2}{y^3} >= 0$$
$$\Delta_{(1,2)} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
    \frac{2}{y} & -\frac{2x}{y^2} \\
    -\frac{2x}{y^2} & \frac{2x^2}{y^3}
\end{vmatrix} = 
\frac{2}{y} * \frac{2x^2}{y^3} - (-\frac{2x}{y^2}) * (-\frac{2x}{y^2}) = 
\frac{4x^2}{y^4} - \frac{4x^2}{y^4} = 0$$

So, all leading minors are non-negative on $\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y>0 \rbrace$.

Hence, Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite.

Hence, function $f(x,y)$ is a convex function on the set $\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y>0 \rbrace$.

Comment: Thank you. +1.On the other hand, I am wondering if this can be proved via a perspective function? Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

If you want something in the spirit of perspective function rather than showing the Hessian is positive semidefinite:

The epigraph of this function can be reduced to a Second Order Cone, which is convex. You can reverse engineer the details by studying CVX's quad_over_lin function https://github.com/cvxr/CVX/blob/master/functions/%40cvx/quad_over_lin.m . I leave you to do that work.

Answer (score 2):

Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite, therefore it is convex:
$$H=\begin{pmatrix} f_{xx}& f_{xy}\\ f_{yx}&f_{yy}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{y}& -\frac{2x}{y^2}\\ -\frac{2x}{y^2}& \frac{2x^2}{y^3}\end{pmatrix}\\
H_1=\frac2y>0\\
H_2=0.$$

Comment: Thank you. +1.On the other hand, I am wondering if this can be proved via a perspective function? Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

**definition:**
the perspective of a function $g : \mathcal{R}^n \to \mathcal{R}$ is the function $f : \mathcal{R}
^n × \mathcal{R} \to \mathcal{R}$,
$$f(x, y) = y\cdot g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right), \textbf{dom}~f = \left\{(x, y)~:~\frac{x}{y} ∈ \textbf{dom}~g,~y > 0\right\}$$
Then $f$ is convex if $g$ is convex. $\square$

Since $g(x) = x^2$ is convex for $x\in\mathcal{R}$. So $f(x,y)=y \cdot g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=y\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{y}$ is convex for $y>0$.

The answer can be found in [[BV04]](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) Example 3.18 or [slide](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/teaching/w10/367.w10/367miscfiles/pages58to60.pdf).

---

> By checking Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite.

This proof can also be found in [[BV04]](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) $\S$3.1.5 or P.73 **Quadratic-over-linear function**

---

> The epigraph of this function can be reduced to a Second Order Cone, which is convex.

This proof can be found in [[BV04]](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) Example 3.4

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1962441)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Mark's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3160462/339790), introduce variable $z$ and define the [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of $f$ via $\frac{x^2}{y} \leq z$ or, since $y > 0$, via $x^2 \leq y z$.  These inequalities (plus $z \geq 0$) can be rewritten as the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y & x \\ x & z\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 $$

Thus, the epigraph of $f$ is a [spectrahedon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) and, thus, **convex**. Hence, $f$ is **convex**.

---

Related:

- [Proof that a function is convex if and only if its epigraph is convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/925835/339790)
- [How do I implement this convex quadratic-linear function in CVX?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086093/339790)