# Convexity of $(x, X) \mapsto x^\top X^{-1} x$

Tags: convex-analysis

> Is the function $f: \mathbb{R}_+^n \times \mathcal{S}_{++}^n$ defined by $$f(x, X) = x^\top X^{-1} x$$ convex on $\mathbb{R}_+^n \times \mathcal{S}_{++}^n$? 
>  **Note:** $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ is the set of component wise non-negative vectors (the non-negative orthant), and $\mathcal{S}_{++}^n$ is the set of positive definite $n\times n$ matrices.

---

**What I’ve tried**

$f$ is an inner product induced by $X^{-1}$, and $X^{-1}$ is a positive definite matrix too. $f$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ because it is convex on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, keeping $X$ fixed. However if $X$ is also allowed to vary then that proof doesn’t apply.

I’m thinking along the lines of: How do we characterise / compute a term like $(\lambda X + (1 - \lambda) Y)^{-1}$?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4088497/339790).

Comment: This is not a quadratic form.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The duplicate has misleading title, it is the same question as here.

Comment: @daw It is not an exact duplicate, though, as here $x$ is in the non-negative orthant.

Comment: @daw that was what I needed thank you! What I don’t understand is why the solution set of $\begin{pmatrix} X & x \\ x^\top & t \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$ would be a convex set.

Comment: @Sean Because it is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron).