# Optimization problem involving the inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have a question related to optimization.

Given natural numbers $n$ and $\ell$, matrices ${\bf K}_1, \dots, {\bf K}_\ell \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ and a vector ${\bf y} \in \Bbb R^n$, define $${\bf K} := s_1 {\bf K}_1 + \dots + s_\ell {\bf K}_\ell + \lambda {\bf I}_n$$ where $s_1, \dots, s_\ell, \lambda \in \Bbb R$, $\lambda > 0$ and ${\bf I}_n$ is the identity matrix. It is also given that the ${\bf K}_1, \dots, {\bf K}_\ell$ are all symmetric and semidefinite so ${\bf K}$ is invertible. The problem is to minimize ${\bf y}^\top {\bf K}^{-1} {\bf y}$ under the constraints $s_1, \dots s_\ell \ge 0$ and $s_1 + \dots + s_\ell = 1$.

---

I have searched that this problem is related to [semidefinite programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) (SDP) but since I have no background on optimization theory, I cannot proceed any further. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are there any conditions on the matrices $K_i$? It is not even clear that clear that $K^{-1}$ exists for general chocies of $K_i$ and $s_i$. If there is a feasible set of $s_i$'s such that $K^{-1}$ does not exist, then one can potentially perturb these values to make the objective arbitrarily large

Comment: If you have an additional constraint that $K$ is positive definite, then your problem can be reformulated as $\min_{s_1, \dots, s_l, t} t$ subject to $y^T K^{-1} y \leq t$, $K = s_1 K_1 + \dotsb + s_n K_n \succ 0$, $s_1, \dots, s_l \geq 0$, $s_1 + \dotsb + s_l = 1$. The constraint $y^T K^{-1} y \leq t$ can be converted into $\begin{pmatrix} t & y^T \\ y & K\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$. This is semidefinite programming.

Comment: Your comments are definitely right so I editted the problem. Could you recommend any references to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4088497/339790)

Comment: Since the matrices are constant, and the $s_i$ are the only variables, it looks like a tweak of the constraint in @RodrigodeAzevedo 's comment should work; however, since the author is new to the field, should probably be written out.

Answer (score 3):

Let me expand on my earlier comment and @RodrigodeAzevedo 's reference.

Your original problem is
\begin{align*}
\min_{s_1, \dots, s_\ell, \lambda, \mathbf{K}} & \quad \mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{y}\\
\text{subject to} & \quad \mathbf{K} = s_1 \mathbf{K}_1 + \dotsb + s_\ell \mathbf{K}_\ell + \lambda \mathbf{I}_n\\
& \quad s_1, \dots, s_\ell \geq 0\\
& \quad s_1 + \dotsb + s_\ell = 1\\
& \quad \lambda > 0\\
& \quad \mathbf{K} \succ 0\\
\end{align*}

If you just want to find a numerical solution to the problem, then [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) or [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/) can do the job. Use the `matrix_frac` function (reference [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.other_atoms.html#matrix-frac)) as your objective, write out all of the above constraints, and that should solve the problem. For guidance on using CVX or CVXPY, first check their documentation. They provide plenty of [examples](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/index.html) to get you started. In case you need additional help with coding, post your question on StackOverflow.

If you want to understand how `matrix_frac` works and how it relates to semidefinite programming, then here are the details.

First, write your problem in equivalent form
\begin{align*}
\min_{s_1, \dots, s_\ell, \lambda, \mathbf{K}, t} & \quad t\\
\text{subject to} & \quad \mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{y} \leq t\\
& \quad \mathbf{K} = s_1 \mathbf{K}_1 + \dotsb + s_\ell \mathbf{K}_\ell + \lambda \mathbf{I}_n\\
& \quad s_1, \dots, s_\ell \geq 0\\
& \quad s_1 + \dotsb + s_\ell = 1\\
& \quad \lambda > 0\\
& \quad \mathbf{K} \succ 0\\
\end{align*}

We want to turn the constraints $\mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{y} \leq t$, $\mathbf{K} \succ 0$ into a condition involving some matrix being positive semidefinite. The key is Schur complement: If you have a symmetric block matrix $X = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B^T\\
B & C
\end{pmatrix}$ and $C \succ 0$, then $X \succeq 0$ if and only if $A - B^T C^{-1} B \succeq 0$.

Using Schur complement, we find that the constraints are equivalent to $\begin{pmatrix}
t & \mathbf{y}^T\\
\mathbf{y} & \mathbf{K}
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$, $\mathbf{K} \succ 0$.

Now your problem can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
\min_{s_1, \dots, s_\ell, \lambda, \mathbf{K}, t} & \quad t\\
\text{subject to} & \quad \begin{pmatrix}
t & \mathbf{y}^T\\
\mathbf{y} & \mathbf{K}
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0\\
& \quad \mathbf{K} = s_1 \mathbf{K}_1 + \dotsb + s_\ell \mathbf{K}_\ell + \lambda \mathbf{I}_n\\
& \quad s_1, \dots, s_\ell \geq 0\\
& \quad s_1 + \dotsb + s_\ell = 1\\
& \quad \lambda > 0\\
& \quad \mathbf{K} \succ 0\\
\end{align*}
This is a bona fide semidefinite program: You just have a linear objective, linear equality and inequality constraints, and semidefinite matrix constraints.

Note that for implementation purposes, you don't need to manually express your problem in this last form. `matrix_frac` automatically does this reduction for you behind the scene.

Comment: Wow, great thanks!