# Rephrase convex constraint to satisfy DCP rules

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, python, cvxpy

<sub>[Crossposted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75637323) on Stack Overflow</sub>

---

I have a convex objective function and a convex constraint of the form $$\frac{y^2}{x} + z \leq 1$$ on the domain $x \geq 0$. However, I'm not sure how to encode this constraint in a way that CVXPY will accept it. It seems to be rejecting it because it can't convince itself that the constraint is convex.

Here is a simple example code:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

n = 5
x = cp.Variable(n)

xtarget = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
A = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n, n])
B = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n, n])
y = A @ x
z = B @ x
obj = cp.sum_squares(xtarget - x)
constraints = [x>= 0, y ** 2 / x + z <= 1]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints)
prob.solve()
```

This gives the error:

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The following constraints are not DCP
```

I have tried to replace `y ** 2 / x + z <= 1` with `cp.multiply(y ** 2, cp.pos_inv(x)) + z <= 1` so that it know that $x$ variable is non-negative. It still gives me the DCP error.

Is there a way to reformulate the problem such that it satisfies the DCP rules?

---

**Addendum**

Thanks, Rodrigo de Azevedo, for [suggesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652625) positive semidefinite programming idea. Here is the code I ended with. I didn't know how to do this cleanly, so here is a hacky way of doing it.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

n = 5
x = cp.Variable(n, pos = True)

xtarget = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
A = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n, n])
B = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n, n])
y = A @ x
z = B @ x
obj = cp.sum_squares(xtarget - x)
constraints = [x>= 0, y ** 2 <= 1, 1 - z >= 0]
Ms = [cp.Variable([2, 2], symmetric = True) for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    constraints.append(Ms[i] >> 0)
    constraints.append(Ms[i][0,0] == x[i])
    constraints.append(Ms[i][0,1] == y[i])
    constraints.append(Ms[i][1,0] == y[i])
    constraints.append(Ms[i][1,1] == 1 - z[i])
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints)
prob.solve()
```

Comment: This looks more like a coding problem than a math problem.

Comment: @ArcticChar That is because you haven't thought about it

Comment: JEK, I don't understand your code.  Why do you define `y` and `z` in terms of `x`?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3157463/339790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) and [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), the given inequalities (plus the inequality $z \leq 1$) can be encapsulated in the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & 1 - z \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$

Can you now translate this to CVXPY? You might want to use [`PSD`](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#attributes) or [`>>`](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#semidefinite-matrices).

Comment: Thank you! That’s a really neat solution! I will try it on the computer tonight and once it works, I will accept as answer.

Comment: @JEK Happy to help. If it works, please consider sharing the code

Comment: Yup. I will try to write it up tonight when I have access to my computer.

Comment: The atom quad_over_lin in cvxpy does the job. Then you can use all SOCP solvers and are not limited to SDP-aware solvers only. And if you want to reformulate it, rather than use a ready-made function, then it will be cheaper to reformulate it directly as SOCP (although an SDP solver will likely presolve a 2x2 SDP to SOCP, but still).

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek That comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You can now consider converting your comment into an answer